# How to fix gdb skipping breakpoints

Tags: debugging, assembly, gdb, x86-64, breakpoints

I wrote an assembly code to test multiplication and division with integers. After assembling the code with -g and compiling it with gcc -g; I put a series of breakpoints in GDB, before and after the arithmetic operations.
Some breakpoints are skipped and GDB ends the debugging session.
What could be happening? I attach example code and picture of it.
Debian 10.8 (gcc 8.3.0-6)and Nasm assembler.
I would appreciate the help.

[test code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4vdCe.jpg)

```
 section .bss
 data: resq 1 
section .text 
global main
 main:
        push rbp
        mov rbp,rsp
        mov rax,77
        mov rbx,2
        mul  rbx
        mov [rel data],rax
        mov rsp,rbp
        pop rbp
        mov rax,60
        mov rdi,0
        syscall
```

ok this is the gdb output; consider two breakpoints, one is mul bx, and the other on mov rsp,rbp; before the syscall exit.

```
Breakpoint 2,  in__libc_csu_init()
(gdb)c
Continuing.
[inferior 1 process(1974) exited normally]
(gdb)
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting for how to format code blocks.

Comment: Can you include a transcript of your gdb session?  As text in a code block in the question if at all possible, please, not a screen shot.  A command like `script(1)` may be useful.

Comment: You just have to put three backticks `\`\`\``, on a line by itself, before and after your code.  Please also fix the directives `BITS 64...` which should be on their own lines but seem to have been wrapped.

Comment: `script(1)` is a Linux command that saves a file with the input and output of an interactive program, so that you can include the gdb output in your post.  Please type `man script` in your terminal to learn about it.  I am not suggesting it as part of the code itself.

Comment: Is not a direct answer to your question, but for such a short code it may be more convenient to single step without breakpoints using `si`/`stepi`.

Comment: Thanks... in just a moment i`ll send gdb ouput

Comment: Thank You  Jester, "si" works just fine... the work wiith breakpoints has become a nightmare.

Comment: Please include the *entire* gdb session.  I suspect something may be wrong with the way you set the breakpoints, but you omitted that part so there's no way to know.

Comment: You can set breakpoints on numeric addresses with `b *0x555...`  (I typically use the mouse to copy/paste an address from the disassembly output from `disas` or from the TUI disassembly window from `layout reg`)